# How to store specific JSON data in PHP and get rid of Undefined Index Notice?

Tags: php, json, api

I'm developing an app using PHP and I'm fetching data via api endpoint. I was able to get the data I want - a huge chunk of it, found here: https://gist.github.com/kamaelxiii/18ef0c1600330b98717b96db00532d6a

Now my blocker is I just want to get and store the specific ID of a player (look for name : kamaelxiii) my code was able to get the ID but the page also displays this message:

**Notice:** Undefined index: name in **C:\xampp\htdocs\vgapp\index.php on line 230**

I'm thinking that this is because I'm looping to the entire `included` block but not all contains the index `name` in it. I've tried adding `break` inside the for loop below but the ID that I'm after is not always the first in the list so there are times that the message above still shows - most of the time.

Here's my line of code that gets the specific ID:

```
if(is_array($finaljson) || is_object($finaljson)){
foreach ($finaljson['included'] as $key => $value) {
        if($value['attributes']['name'] === $username){
            $userid = $value['id'];
        }
}
```

Comment: please provide the information in the $finaljson object

Comment: Your link just says "We are trying to connect to the server."

Comment: you can't use an array style accessor on an object so the `is_object` check is just an invitation for this to fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get rid of Notice, Then just use empty() or isset() in your foreach loop's if condition. below is the code.

```
 if(is_array($finaljson) || is_object($finaljson)){
 foreach ($finaljson['included'] as $key => $value) {
 //you can use empty check 
    if(!empty($value['attributes']['name']) && $value['attributes']['name'] === $username){
            $userid = $value['id'];
    }
//or you can use isset 
   if(isset($value['attributes']['name']) && $value['attributes']['name'] === $username){
            $userid = $value['id'];
    }
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

It is not a serious problem.

```
error_reporting(0);
```

OR:

```
 if(@$value['attributes']['name'] === $username){
            $userid = $value['id'];
        }
```

Comment: Sweeping a problem under the rug does not make it go away.